# How do I make a mask that dictates which layers are visible in Unity?

Tags: unity, camera, transformation, transparency, masking

I'm trying to create an effect where the player progresses from one level to the next by a portal appearing as a rip in the fabric of time, and the portal grows until it'd half the screen, then inverts and closes around the previous scene and disappears. Here's a gif trying to explain what I mean, it's kind of like a Looney Toons = > Negative Looney Toons effect:

[image: Here is the gif]

I have managed to switch from one camera to another in the exact same position but different culling masks to isolate which camera is responsible for which layer. So now it seems like I'd want some sort of animation mask that tells which dictates which camera should be enabled for a certain part of the screen, but I don't think it works that way.

Any advice on the direction to take this in would be greatly appreciate it. Below is the effect I got working and the code that makes it work.

[Video on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgurQ.jpg)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

namespace sq
{
    public class CamSwapper : MonoBehaviour {
        public Camera mainCamera;
        private Camera thisCamera;

        private void Update() {
            var thisTransform = transform;
            var mainCamTransform = mainCamera.transform;
            
            thisTransform.position = mainCamTransform.position;
            thisTransform.rotation = mainCamTransform.rotation;
        }

        private void Start() {
            thisCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();
            thisCamera.enabled = false;
            StartCoroutine(nameof(Swap_Cameras_After_10_Seconds));
        }

        private IEnumerator Swap_Cameras_After_10_Seconds() {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(10f);
            Swap_Cameras();
        }

        private void Swap_Cameras() {
            mainCamera.enabled = !mainCamera.enabled;
            thisCamera.enabled = !thisCamera.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```